# How to test IllegalStateException for getResultList of JAP Query

Tags: spring, jpa, junit

I was trying to write a test for "IllegalStateException for getResultList of JAP Query". I am using spring to handle the transaction. Can anybody help me to produce this exception?

Sample Code

```
@Test (expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void shouldThroughIllegalStateException() throws Exception {
        List<SomeEntity> someEntitys= someDao.getAlldata();
    }
```

Regards
Rajib

Comment: Please provide more info. Are you testing the `someDao`? What are the contents of the `getAllData`? Without any additional information I would suggest that you mock the `DataSource`. If using spring you might look into `Springockito`.

Comment: Thanks John, I think I should explore on Springockito. Let you know the result soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Springockito to resolve this problem. Easy to use mocking framework.